# Entity Framework Id Object Name Collision Problem

Tags: entity-framework-core

So I'm running into an annoying problem with EF Core 6.0 where I am getting a naming conflict when mapping using strongly typed Value Objects as Id's.

So the following, using straight Guid's as Id's, works:

```
public class User {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole {
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class UserEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User> {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder) {
        builder.ToTable("User", SchemaNames.Application);
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id).HasName("Id");
        builder.HasMany(d => d.Roles);
    }
}

internal sealed class UserRoleValueTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserRole> {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserRole> builder) {
        builder.ToTable("UserRoles", SchemaNames.Application);
        builder.HasKey(userRole => new { userRole.UserId, userRole.RoleId });
        builder.Property("UserId").HasColumnName("UserId");
        builder.Property("RoleId").HasColumnName("RoleId");            
    }
}

User user = new User() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
user.Roles.Add(new UserRole() { UserId = user.Id.Value, RoleId = roleId });
context.Users.AddAsync(user);
```

However when trying to use strongly typed Id's and perform an Add:

```
public class UserId : TypedIdValue {
    public UserId(Guid value) : base(value) { }
}

public class User {
    public UserId Id { get; set; }
    public List<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}

User user = new User() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
user.Roles.Add(new UserRole() { UserId = user.Id.Value, RoleId = roleId });
context.Users.AddAsync(user);
```

I get - `SqlException: Invalid column name 'UserId1'.`

I am using a custom `ValueConverterSelector` and `ValueConverter` registered with the `DbContextOptionsBuilder` to facilitate the strongly typed Id's.

Clearly it's tripping up over there being a UserId object for Id and UserId field in the UserRole object, but I'm at a loss as to how to resolve this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Guid` is pretty strongly-typed too. You're trying to use your own custom value type as a property type in a case where this doesn't offer any benefits. The error complains about relations, not the value type mapping. You have both a `UserId` type and a `UserId` property used by the `User` class. That's not a good idea. Try renaming the type to `UserIdentity`

Comment: How much code have you written already to replace `Guid` with custom types? What benefit did you expect to get from this?

Comment: I haven't written very much code yet, still just getting things up and running so can just switch to Guids, which I think I will just do. When all is and done I guess it doesn't actually add that much value but I read you should do it because your Id type is a persistence concern, i.e. outside of your domain, could be a Guid, could be an Int etc.

Comment: There's a difference between book architectures and real application architectures. `Just in case` or `best practice` code is a really bad idea unless you can point to the real benefits it offers you in this project, right now. The extra/non-conventional code requires maintenance and can easily conflict with the way libraries work - as you found out.